# Deploying ESXi onto Hyper-V on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vmware-esxi, hyper-v, vmware-vsphere

Can I run ESXi onto Hyper-V which is deployed on AWS?

Hyper-V can be deployed on AWS [Running Hyper-V on Amazon EC2 Bare Metal Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-hyper-v-on-amazon-ec2-bare-metal-instances/)
.

Once Hyper-V is ready, ESXi can be installed according to [Install VMware ESXi on a Hyper-V](https://thesolving.com/virtualization/install-vmware-esxi-hyper-v/). My concern is, whether this can be done on AWS.

[VMware Cloud for AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/vmware/) is not an option for me, as well as getting OVA image of ESXi and upload it as AMIs (I got an error while uploading `"StatusMessage": "ClientError: EFI partition detected. UEFI booting is not supported in EC2."`) because I need to have an EC2 instance that runs ESXi if someone has another suggestion

Comment: `Can I run ESXi onto Hyper-V which is deployed on AWS?` - Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @joeqwerty well, I need for testing SR MPLS in which I will NFV manager and it is installed on ESXi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't. Nested ESXi is not supported by VMware: [[lack of] Support for running ESXi/ESX as a nested virtualization solution](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2009916).

Adding on another nested hypervisor layer simply to get around an image import utility seems too complicated. Where is the evidence that anyone has done ESXi on Hyper-V on EC2 metal before, even in an unsupported configuration?

You have not stated why ESXi compute is important for this workload. VMs can be converted to different hypervisors. More cloud native networking products exist, VMware might pitch you a solution based on NSX-T.

Comment: Well, that's right! Thank you. 
I would like to run an NFV manager that has a set of different Network Functions. This NFV manager will use the SFC that it is preconfigured in the Segment Routing domain in which there are CSR1000v routers deployed on AWS.